# Concatenating two lists with Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in Access, but I have two tables... one of which is a sold table that includes fields like SKU, price sold, sold date, and item descripton, and I also have a stock table which has the SKU, date in, retail price, and item description.

I want a master item list of all the items from the sold and stock table where there are no duplicates.

Is this even possible?

Comment: "No duplicates" -- you only want records that don't exist in both tables?  Or you want each SKU to appear only once?

Answer (score 1):

A [`union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208962(v=office.12).aspx) does just that:

```
select  col1
,       col2
,       ...
from    table1
union
select  col1
,       col2
,       ...
from    table2
```

No duplicate records are returned unless you include the `all` predicate (as in `union all`.)